# Postgres - UPDATE with CASE won't work on enum column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `fruits` table:

```
--------------------------------
id | event_date   | fruit_type |
--------------------------------
1  | '2017-01-01' | apple      |
2  | '2018-01-01' | orange     |
3  | '2019-01-01' | pear       |
```

The `fruit_type` column is of type `enum` and can take the following options:

- apple
- orange
- pear

I run into a problem when trying to update the `fruit_type` column using `CASE`. If I use the following `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE fruits
SET fruit_type = CASE WHEN event_date = '2019-01-01' THEN 'apple' END;
```

I get the error:

> [42804] ERROR: column "fruit_type" is of type "enum_fruits_fruit_type" but expression is of type text Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

If I do an `UPDATE` statement without `CASE`, then I am able to update the column just fine:

```
UPDATE fruits
SET fruit_type = 'apple'
WHERE date = '2019-01-01';
```

I need to use `CASE` in my `UPDATE` statement, but I can't seem to if the column is of type `enum`. Is there any way I can get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to explicitly cast the type to the enum type :

```
UPDATE fruits
SET fruit_type = CASE WHEN event_date = '2019-01-01' THEN 'apple'::enum_fruits_fruit_type END;
```

I think when you directly set the column , postgresql does it for you automatically but it comes to conditions, it can't do it .